# Reset 'Top' command default view on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

I met a problem when using linux top command on macOS. The default top open view now looks like

[image: Current top view]

It displays too many unnecessary columns and didn't sort by CPU or MEM by default. I remember it used to be like

[image: old top view]

Anyone know how to change it back? I've checked my home folder that there is no .toprc file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no default view settings for top. Did you maybe use an alias which included some command line parameters in the past?

Comment: It just happened today. I checked command history that no parameters ever been set while using top command. It used to be showing the black image format when I typed “top” in terminal.

Comment: If it was aliased you don‘t see anything in the history. But is your problem the black vs white screen or the content shown? The black one doesn’t look like standard macOS `top`, did you have another version installed through Homebrew or similar?

Comment: Where did you get the second screenshot from?

Comment: Probably my memory fails me. I thought it was my machine's problem.
Thanks, Scot, patrix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

top will generally display as many columns as the width of your window will allow. But to change the sort to cpu (high to low), you can type the following within top:

`o` to select primary sort

`-cpu` to sort by decreasing CPU usage

You can add a secondary sort if desired:

`O` to select secondary sort

`-mem` to sort by decreasing memory usage

`?` will show you all options, along with the current sort selections - see below image:
[image]

You can also call these options explicitly from the command line, if desired, like this:

To see your longest running processes

`top -o time -user $(whoami)`

Comment: Check the two images I attached. The first line is different. The first one begins with "Processes" and the second one begins with "top". I believe there is something wrong because it used be like the second one on my macbook.

Comment: @EasonChen The bottom one (white text on black background) appears to be a version of top running on Linux, the top one (black text on white background) appears to be the version runing on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

`top` store user preferences in `.toprc` file.  Check if such file exist into your home :

```
ll ~/.toprc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dba dba 617 Nov 29 11:16 /home/dba/.toprc
```

If you want to definitively reset your preferences, simply delete this file and restart `top`

```
rm ~/.toprc
top
```

Answer (score -1):

In terminal run: top -o cpu -O mem or create alias like t to run it

Comment: How does this improve on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310867/237 which shows `top -o time -user $(whoami)` and a lot more?